# Word for the sound of a box cutter retracting: open and close

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

The sound of an exacto (box cutter) knife retracting in and out. Open and close. Sound effect.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Can you describe the sound effect of both?

Comment: An X-acto Knife isn't the same as a box cutter. An X-acto knife with retractable blade is much finer and far less robust, something that you hold like a pencil that's designed for doing fine-arts projects with precision or "exactness," while a box cutter is much girthier and more robust, something you hold in your fist that's designed for utility purposes, like opening boxes and cutting carpet, crude uses not requiring precision or "exactness" but durability and strength. They don't make the same sound opening and closing, so you'll have to decide exactly what it is you want described.

Comment: When you hold it in your hand, retracting in and out. Like when you hold a lighter, clicking it on and off. That's kind of sound I'm looking for, retracting in and out. Not cutting on anything. Does it make sense?

Comment: You've already used the best word in your last comment: you wrote "clicking", that's exactly what I was going to suggest. Do you have a reason for rejecting it?

Comment: I kinda like ***snick***

Comment: @Jim Thst's good as well!

Comment: I think **rattle** is a good contestant: "*to give out or cause a rapid succession of short, sharp sounds, as in consequence of agitation and repeated concussions*" ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rattle))

Comment: It's got kind of a _ratcheting_ sound until it clicks into the locked position.

Comment: Thank you guys, you are a great help.